# Semiclassical transport -- can closed orbits be closed outside of the First Brillouin Zone?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiclassical, transport-phenomena

In Chapter 12, Ashcroft and Mermin describe the various differences which can arise with bands which have open orbits, these orbits being the path through $k$-space of an electron under a magnetic (and potentially electric) field.

My question is, how are *closed* orbits defined? More specifically still, is it possible for an orbit not to close in BZ1 (or whatever primitive cell of $k$-space is chosen), and yet somehow close on itself while "using" a larger region of $k$-space to do so?